# Too Many Nodes Slows My Android Godot Game Down

Tags: godot, gdscript

My Game is a modern bubble shooter and i have like 100 bubbles. They all have script but script doesnt have process or physics process. But the game still has like 5 fps on a Samsung S8 Plus. The phone isnt that old. At least for a bubble shooter. And i'm sure that the problem is the amount of bubbles bc when bubbles begins being generated themselves the game is getting slower and slower bt the amount. IDK how to fix it. It has 60 fps both in pc and my 2019 phone. And when you shoot the bubbles it gets faster bc there arent that bubbles left.

Godot version 3.2.3

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Test and figure out if the bottleneck is physics or graphics. However, two approaches to optimize the physics come to mind: 1. Use a particle system for the bubbles. 2. Use `PhysicsServer` directly. Edit: you are using GLES2, right?

Comment: I solved it with a optimization to nodes. Thanks

Comment: I know this is a little late, but it would be awesome if you described the optimizations you have made as an answer to your post.